# MongoDB Aggregation - $lookup without grouping 'as'

Tags: mongodb

what I want to do is to join `bookmarks` with `events` that its document's status is `activated`. and also I want to replace roots with joined data list. hence, I'm currently running query like this:

```
db.bookmarks.aggregate(
[
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "events",
            "let": {"eventId": "event_id"},
            "pipeline": [
                {
                     "$match": {"$expr": {"$and": [{"$eq": ["$_id", "$$eventId"]}, {"$eq": ["$status", "activated"]}]}
                }
            ],
            "as": "events"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {"path": "$events", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": True}
    },
    {
        "$replaceWith": "$events"
    },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "page_info": [{"$count": "total_count"}],
            "data_list": {
                [{"$skip": 0}, {"$limit": 10}]
            }
        }
    }
]
)
```

but here's problem, when event's status doesn't match with `activated`, it causes error  like this:

```
PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: 'replacement document' must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: MISSING. Type of resulting value: 'missing'
```

my query only works when all the documents are fully joined.
what is the best way of replacing root with joined data list?

Comment: Have you tried out `$replaceRoot`?

Comment: Does `$replaceRoot` not generate the same error? Seems to be doing so for me, [playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nnGlOND-Fj4). I also have to ask - what do you want the output document to be when `events` is empty?

Comment: I've tried `$replaceRoot` with `$ifNull` so that it replace roots with `{}` if `events` is empty. This doesn't return the error but `total_count` still counts total documents whether null or not. My exact requirement is to exclude empty `events` and not count excluded documents.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74896571/mongodb-aggregation-lookup-without-grouping-as?noredirect=1#comment132188421_74896571):

> My exact requirement is to exclude empty events and not count excluded documents.

I think the solution here is to use the default `$unwind` settings. Currently you are specifically setting `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` to `true` in your `$unwind` stage. Per [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#document-operand-with-options), the description of this parameter is:

> Optional.
>
> - If `true`, if the path is null, missing, or an empty array, `$unwind` outputs the document.
> - If `false`, if path is `null`, missing, or an empty array, `$unwind` does not output a document.
>
> The default value is `false`.

So the trailing `$facet` in your pipeline is receiving (and therefor counting) the empty documents precisely because you are jumping through hoops (via that preservation setting in `$unwind` and the `$ifNull` in `$replaceRoot`) to get them there. To get the behavior that you are looking for, change the value of that setting to `false`:

```
    {
        "$unwind": {"path": "$events", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": False}
    },
```

Or, since that's the default value, you can use the simpler syntax:

```
    {
        "$unwind": "$events"
    },
```

You can play around with the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` setting in [this playground sandbox](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z5jQDKrm_db). Simple syntax variant is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zunwySNYvWi).